# Is it random walk?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, random-walk

I would like to ask a question about random walk. Campbell, Lo & Mackinlay defined the random walk, in the following way (RW3):

$$
cov[f(r_{t}),g(r_{t+k})]=0,\qquad k\neq0
$$

for all $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$, where $f(\cdot)$
and $g(\cdot)$ are linear functions, and $\{r_{t}\}$
is a series of returns. So, the question is about the following equation: 
$$
r_{t}=\alpha\varepsilon_{t-1}^{2}+\varepsilon_{t},\qquad\varepsilon_{t}\sim IID(0,\sigma^{2}).
$$

Is it random walk or not? And why? 
(I have an idea, but i don't know, if it's true.)

Thanks

Comment: It is good practice here to share your idea, meaning: Show any work and progress that you have done/made yourself.

Comment: $f(\cdot)$
  and $g(\cdot)$
  can be written as $f(x)=ax+b$
  and $g(y)=cy+d$
 . Then,
$$
cov[f(r_{t});g(r_{t+k})]=ac\alpha^{2}(E[\varepsilon_{t-1}^{2}\varepsilon_{t+k-1}^{2}]-E[\varepsilon_{t-1}^{2}]E[\varepsilon_{t+k-1}^{2}])+ac\alpha(E[\varepsilon_{t-1}^{2}\varepsilon_{t+k}]-E[\varepsilon_{t-1}^{2}]E[\varepsilon_{t+k}])+ac\alpha(E[\varepsilon_{t}\varepsilon_{t+k-1}^{2}]-E[\varepsilon_{t}]E[\varepsilon_{t+k-1}^{2}])
$$

If $k=\pm1$
 , then it's $ac\alpha(E[\varepsilon_{t}^{3}])$
 , else it's 0. So it can be only 0 if $E[\varepsilon_{t}^{3}]=0$
 .

Comment: Include this not as comment, but within the body of the question...